# How to enable STRICT_STUBS while using Mockito.mock()

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, kotlin, mockito

I've found only three ways how to enable `STRICT_STUBS` in Mockito ([See documemantation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.22.0/org/mockito/quality/Strictness.html#STRICT_STUBS))

1. `MockitoJunitRunner`
2. `MockitoJUnit.rule().strictness(Strictness.STRICT_STUBS)`
3. `Mockito.mockitoSession()
      .initMocks(this)
      .strictness(Strictness.STRICT_STUBS)
      .startMocking()`

All of them require to declare stubs via annotations (`@Mock lateinit var api: MyApi` ). But I'm using [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) and declare stubs like that:

`val api: MyApi = mock()`

or like that:

```
val api:MyApi = mock{
  on { call("expected-param") } doReturn something
}
```

Under the hood it uses [Mockit.mock](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.22.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mock-java.lang.Class-org.mockito.MockSettings-) method.

**Question 1**: how can I enable `STRICT_STUBS` when I use [Mockit.mock](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.22.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mock-java.lang.Class-org.mockito.MockSettings-) ?

**Question 2**: Perhaps it's possible to enable `STRICT_STUBS` for everything regardless how mock is defined?

**Update 1**. Test example

```
interface Foo {
    fun doFoo(value: String): String
}

class Boo(private val foo: Foo) {
    fun doBoo(value: String): String {
        return foo.doFoo("$value with Boo")
    }
}

class ExampleTest {
    @get:Rule val rule = MockitoJUnit.rule().strictness(Strictness.STRICT_STUBS)
    // doesn't work when replaced with var mockedFoo: Foo = Mockito.mock(Foo::class.java)
    @Mock lateinit var mockedFoo: Foo
    lateinit var booUnderTest: Boo

    @Before fun setUp() {
        booUnderTest = Boo(mockedFoo)
    }

    @Test fun withEmptyString() {
        `when`(mockedFoo.doFoo(" with Boo")).thenReturn("empty boo")
        // should fail, because this interaction is not used
        `when`(mockedFoo.doFoo("Foo with Boo")).thenReturn("complete")
        booUnderTest.doBoo("")
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockedFoo)
    }

    @Test fun withRealString() {
        `when`(mockedFoo.doFoo("Foo with Boo")).thenReturn("complete")
        booUnderTest.doBoo("Foo")
        // this test should pass because with STRICT stubbing no need to call verify
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockedFoo)
    }
}
```

Strict stubbing works, when stub is defined as `@Mock lateinit var mockedFoo: Foo`. When I replace it with `var mockedFoo: Foo = Mockito.mock(Foo::class.java)` strict stubbing is not working anymore.

**Update 2. Answer.**. `Mockito.mock` works, if called after enabling strict mode.

```
class ExampleTest {
    @get:Rule val rule = MockitoJUnit.rule().strictness(Strictness.STRICT_STUBS)
    lateinit var mockedFoo: Foo
    lateinit var booUnderTest: Boo
    @Before fun setUp() {
        mockedFoo = Mockito.mock(Foo::class.java)
        booUnderTest = Boo(mockedFoo)
    }

    @Test fun withEmptyString() {
        `when`(mockedFoo.doFoo(" with Boo")).thenReturn("empty boo")
        // should fail, because this interaction is not used
        `when`(mockedFoo.doFoo("Foo with Boo")).thenReturn("complete")
        booUnderTest.doBoo("")
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockedFoo)
    }

    @Test fun withRealString() {
        `when`(mockedFoo.doFoo("Foo with Boo")).thenReturn("complete")
        booUnderTest.doBoo("Foo")
        // this test should pass because with STRICT stubbing no need to call verify
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockedFoo)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

STRICT_STUBS need additional logic to verify what has and what hasn't been invoked after test, that is why it's rather configured on whole test level. 
That being said, any of the three ways should work with plain `Mockito.mock` method (and with given example provided it uses `Mockito.mock` under the hood).

Comment: Yes, STRICT_STUBS works on whole test level. I guess, that's reason why `Mockito.mock` doesn't work. Because each mock is created "individually". I updated the question with test example, to show how I see that it's not working.

Comment: After further experiments, I've found that `Mockit.mock` is working when I call it in `setUp` method. Basically, it means that I shouldn't create mocks before setting strict mode.